# Retrieving data via REF CURSOR vs via SQL query shows data in different order

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this strange behaviour in a query using Oracle 10g database.

I invoke this stored procedure contained in a package:

```
SQL> VAR RC REFCURSOR
SQL> EXEC MyPackage.MyProcedure('ATLANTICO', :RC )

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> PRINT RC
--prints the data
LURUACO
TUBARA
CGTO SALGAR
ALPES DE SEVILLA
MANATI
SOLEDAD
USIACURI
CGTO SANTA CRUZ
PONEDERA
CGTO JUAN MINA
PALMAR DE VARELA
PIOJO
SANTA LUCIA
BARRANQUILLA
POLONUEVO
REPELON
SANTO TOMAS
SUAN
JUAN DE ACOSTA
BARANOA
MALAMBO
PUERTO COLOMBIA
SABANALARGA
CGTO PATILLA
GALAPA
SABANAGRANDE
CAMPO DE LA CRUZ
EDUARDO SANTOS (LA PLAYA)
```

This is the definition of the stored procedure in the package:

```
PROCEDURE MyProcedure(iDEPTO IN VARCHAR2,oCURSOR OUT MYREFCUR) IS
BEGIN
OPEN oCURSOR FOR
select distinct city from MyTable where state=iDEPTO;
END;
```

If I execute the query outside of the package, this is what I'm getting:

```
SQL> select distinct city from MyTable where state='ATLANTICO';

--data retrieved
ALPES DE SEVILLA
BARANOA
BARRANQUILLA
CAMPO DE LA CRUZ
CGTO JUAN MINA
CGTO PATILLA
CGTO SALGAR
CGTO SANTA CRUZ
EDUARDO SANTOS (LA PLAYA)
GALAPA
JUAN DE ACOSTA
LURUACO
MALAMBO
MANATI
PALMAR DE VARELA
PIOJO
POLONUEVO
PONEDERA
PUERTO COLOMBIA
REPELON
SABANAGRANDE
SABANALARGA
SANTA LUCIA
SANTO TOMAS
SOLEDAD
SUAN
TUBARA
USIACURI
28 rows selected.
```

As you can see, I am not applying sorting neither in the stored procedure nor in the SQL query. So, why does the cursor return disordered data, using the same query? Is there a "scientific" explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither query has an `ORDER BY` clause so the order in which Oracle happens to return the data is arbitrary.  It is entirely valid for Oracle to return the data in any order.  And there is no guarantee that you'll get the same order over time.  If you care about the order in which data is returned, you must include an `ORDER BY` clause.

Getting a bit further into the details, I would wager that if you looked at the query plans for these two queries, you'd see that Oracle is taking a different approach to removing the duplicate rows.  In the query using the bind variable, my guess is that it is doing a hash.  In the query using the literal, my guess is that it is doing a sort.  Of course, that's just a guess.  You'd need to post the query plans for anyone to be certain.